# Should using entity or value object when reference to an entity of another bounded context?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my domain, I have two bounded context, `identity` and `management`.

In `identity` bounded context, I have `user` entity. And management I have `visitor` and `manager`. Both `visitor` and `manager` have some different attributes, and both reference to `user`.

If `visitor` and `manager` are entities, can I use user's ID for their ID? My intent is having api like `visitors/:userID`.

If they are value objects, then how I can persist attributes for each type of objects?

Answer (score 0):

When having different bounded context, it is important to keep them isolated, as they share the same ubiquitous language, but the meaning is different from one context to another.

It is totally possible to have such design. For instance, in your bounded context `identity`, you have a Value Object `UserId` (most likely). This can be composed of different attributes, but to keep this easy, let's say it just encapsulates a `String`.

Then, in your `management` bounded context, you can use a Value Object `UserId`, but specific to your bounded context, in a new class.

Then, about your `entities` `visitor` and `manager`: Both are Aggregate Root, and so they are `entities`. They are simply the entry point to your Aggregate. They are entities, but their ID is a value object `UserId`.

You end up with the following possible code:

```
public class Visitor {
    private UserId id;
    // some other attributes and domain method    
}

public class Manager {
    private UserId id;
    // some other attributes and domain method    
}
```

This is a really limited example, but to sum up, you have:

- `Identity` bounded context: 1 entity `User` and 1 VO `UserId`
- `Management` bounded context: 2 entities `Visitor` `Manager` and 1 VO `UserId`

For further reading, I recommend this blog to delve deeper into properly design an aggregate:

- [Vaugh Vernon - DDD Comunity - Effective aggregate design](https://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)
- Also this book: **Implementing Domain Driven Design** By *Vaugh Vernon*